# What is the difference between 入 and 进?

Tags: difference

Both seems to mean "to enter".   I had a feeling that the  入 is more "to put into" while the 进 is "to enter" ? But I also saw the "entrence" using 入.

Comment: 他可以“进” 而不“入”。  入 means he will be in (a room, etc), while 进 is an action or trial only (he try to enter but there are possiblity something/somebody blocks him).  just like you "look to" east but  "see" nothing.

Answer (score 5):

入 (to put **into**/ to enter **into**)

进 (to **advance**/ to **advance** and enter)

> **进入** (**advance into**/ **to enter**) is a compound word
>
> - 进(advance) is the main verb
> - 入(into) is the resultative/ directional verb particle

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have seen, personally, I see 入口 used as a noun, and 进 used as a verb.